# How do I structure a Cross Referenceble Multi Language Dictionary Database?

Tags: database-design

This database should support three way-cross referencing between Mongolian, English, an Chinese, as well as stand as a dictionary of its own for each language.

The information encoded for **English** would include things like: Word, IPA pronunciation (s), definition(s), example sentence(s), plural spelling, plural pronunciation, synonyms, antonyms, word type, study note(s), Chinese equivalent(s), Mongolian C. equivalent(s), Mongolian S. equivalent(s)

**Chinese**: Traditional character, Simplified character, definition(s), pinyin pronunciation(s), example sentence(s), synonyms, antonyms, HSK test level, strokes, radical(s), lookup radical,  collocating measure words, word type,  simple explanation of character,  in depth explanation of character, study note(s), English equivalent(s), Mongolian C. equivalent(s), Mongolian S. equivalent(s)

**Mongolian Cyrillic**: Cyrillic word, Cyrillic definition, Cyrillic definition(s), Cyrillic examples, c. synonyms, c. antonyms, Chinese equivalents, Inner Mongolian (script) equivalent meaning, Mongolians script equivalent spelling,Eng. Equiv.(s), Chin. Eqiv.(s)

**Mongolian script**: script, script alternative ending, script definition(s), script definition(s), s. synonyms, s. antonyms word type(s), study note(s), Eng. Equiv.(s), Chin. Eqiv.(s), Outer Mongolian (Cyrillic) equivalent meaning(s), Mongolian Cyrillic equivalent spelling.

I'm very new with databases. At first I considered making a table for each language, but this leaves a problem with all plural (s) items.
Now I wonder if I need a table for each item of each language in order to ensure I don't wind up not being able to include all the information I need. I was thinking, for each entry the link between languages would be base on it's ID/PK.

1. Do I have the right idea with the database?
2. If I want to include this much information, then each item that may include multiple values needs its own table, no?
3. But, it's true that editing this should be easy, provided each is linked by it's PK, I can edit all values from a language (or cross language) from one interface, right?
4. What about the issue of not knowing how many multiple entries there may be. For instance, some words may have more equivalents, or more same language synonyms than others. Is this an issue, or do you just add more columns in the table, no problem?

Comment: It is customary to comment on, vote for, and/or accept answers

Comment: I'm also interested in doing almost exactly the same project (Mongolian, English, Chinese Dictionary). I didn't know someone else had already been working on it. Did you ever finish or get any further in this?

Comment: I see from your profile you still log on occasionally. Did you ever pursue this any more?

Answer (score 4):

I would go about having a unified structure for all languages. This will make it easier to maintain, plus write up an editor for it.

Additionally, I would [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the attributes, so you don't have many repeated or unused columns. This also helps in cases where an attribute can have multiple values, like multiple definitions or multiple plural forms.

This is how I would start, I'm leaving many design decisions open, such as whether to always use number ids, whether foreign key constraints are enforced, etc. I've bolded the table name and the primary key(s).

- Table: **word_language** (domain table)

  - **word_id**: a number, probably auto incrementing. primary key, FK to word_attributes
  - language(_id): either a string (eg: "english"), a FK into "languages" domain table, or both
  - name (optional, could also be an attribute): a string, the word (eg: "lamp")
- Table: **word_attributes** (one to many)

  - **word_id**: primary key, FK to word_language
  - attribute(_id|_key): either a FK to a "attributes" domain table, a string (eg: "plural"), or both
  - attribute_value: a string, the actual value (eg: "lamps")
- Table: **languages** (optional, domain table)

  - **language(_id)**: either an auto-incrementing number or a string (eg: english) primary key
  - name (optional, use if language if is an id): string (eg: "english"), etc
  - (other useful columns describing languages)
- Table: **attributes** (optional, domain table)

  - **attribute(_id|_key)**: number or string, primary key
  - **language(_id)** (optional): makes it easy to look up what attributes a language has, part of primary key
  - description: describe the attribute, perhaps what will show up in the editing tool
- Table: **equivalents** (optional, many to many, could also be an attribute)

  - **source_word_id**: a word primary key
  - destination_word_id: equivalent word in a different language